# How can I run git commands via shell script?

Tags: git, shell, command

I have my main repo on my server and two clones.

One clone is on my local for editing. Another copy is on my server in the public folder to pull the changes and view them live.

The current routine I'm going through is edit local -> log into my server to the public folder  and do a git pull to see the updated changes.

I would like to use the git hooks "post-receive" shell script to change into the public folder and do a git pull origin master...I just can't seem to figure out how to do this properly. I tried this using:

```
cd /home/demo/public_html/example.com/public/ && `git status`
```

But the return I get is "not a repository"

However, if I run `cd /home/demo/public_html/example.com/public/ && ls`

I WILL get the contents of the public folder (so I'm moving into the right place) Thanks in advanced!

UPDATE:

Should have mentioned I was trying this with and without ticks

Comment: where is your .git folder located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try unsetting the GIT_DIR env variable before doing the git pull or the git status for test.

```
unset GIT_DIR
```

Comment: That's it, now just gotta get around the remote: Permission denied (publickey).

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
cd /home/demo/public_html/example.com/public/ && git status
```

The backticks are used to capture the output of a command in shell variable, for example:

```
x=`ls`
```

will put the output of `ls` into the variable `x`.

Comment: This or similar was the best way for me.  I found that git behaved differently when run from a shell script.  The -C option does not work and I had to prefix the git command with a cd to the relevant directory as you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually including the backquotes around `git status`? That is, are you writing `` cd ... && `git status` `` or `cd ... && git status`? If you're writing the first one, then what that's doing is evaluating the `git status` command, and then trying to interpret the results of that as another command to execute. Remove the backquotes, and you should just get the result of `git status`, not an error as it tries to interpret its results as a command.